# How to remove line from row?

Tags: css, html-table, bootstrap-4

How to remove the line from the table rows? See below:

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <br /><br /><br />
  <table class="table">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="text-align: center;">
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Buy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

How to remove the line from the table rows? See Above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `table-borderless` class to `table` tag. Reference [here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/content/tables/#borderless-table).

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <br /><br /><br />
  <table class="table table-borderless">
    <tbody>
      <tr style="text-align: center;" class="">
        <td>Quantity</td>
        <td>Buy</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="quantity" placeholder="Quantity" name="quantity"></td>
        <td><input type="number" class="form-control" id="buy" placeholder="Buy Amount" name="buy"></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```